# Viewbag: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddEmployee(EmpModel emp)
        {
            try
            {
                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    EmpRepository empRepository = new EmpRepository();
                    empRepository.AddEmployee(emp);
                    ViewBag.Message("Employee Record Successfully");
                }                

                return View(new EmpModel());
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

View

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    @ViewBag.Message
</div>
```

Getting the exception as I mentioned in the title of this problem. What am I missing here?

Comment: If the modelstate isn't valid, then the Message won't be set. So there are potential circumstances where Message would not be populated. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: P.S. as a general point, `catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }` is an anti-pattern and achieves nothing (except wasting CPU cycles). If you're just going to re-throw the exact same exception, what is the point of this clause? Catching should be done for a reason - e.g. typically to log the error, hide it from the user, prevent the program crashing and move to some other more acceptable state (e.g. showing user-friendly message, allowing re-try or similar). Catching just to re-throw is completely pointless.

Comment: @ADyson It passes through that condition and all the data stored in the database perfectly. When it comes to Viewbag it goes to catch exception.

Comment: @ADyson you are right.. just placed there because the message isn't showing up in the view. to check that i added that try catch.. thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that fills the value to viewbag using below syntax

```
ViewBag.Message = "put your content";
```

And 1 more thing as per your code the viewbag exists only when your model state validation fulfills so make sure that you have checked null on the view `(.cshtml)` before using it.

Comment: @Krish You should consider accepting this answer by clicking the check-mark if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Just changed the following code

```
ViewBag.Message("Employee Record Successfully");
```

to

```
ViewBag.Message = "Employee Record Successfully";
```

Comment: @KaranEkkawala Yes.